# Programmatically step through sine wave at uniformly spaced points

Tags: function, trigonometry

Consider a sine wave w/ unit amplitude and wavelength `2 * pi`. I want to calculate points along this function such that the Euclidean distance between any two consecutive points is constant. How can I vary theta from `0` to `2 * pi` such that the points `(theta, sin(theta))` are spaced accordingly?

I've coded an iterative approach that works. It just steps theta in small increments and checks the distance between the last point and potential new point. I have the desired angle when this distance is within a reasonable delta of the constant point-to-point distance. I'm wondering if there's a non-iterative way to find the desired angles.

- Yes, I'm referring to Euclidian distance (as opposed to arc length)
- Approximately 100 points along the curve between zero and `2 * pi` should be adequate

Comment: **Hint:** The pythagorean theorem.  By "cartesian distance," I assume you mean the distance along the X axis, yes?

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/sine-cosine-tangent.html

Comment: When the drivative function has a larger magnitude then the points should be closer together (along the `theta`-axis), right? You know the derivative function is `cos(theta)`. Maybe you could use that?

Comment: Well clearly one set of such angles is [0, pi, 2*pi] but presumably you have a more specific requirement than that?

Comment: May be interesting, but indeed not very clear. Are you talking about the *euclidean* distance of two points? Or about the distance of two points referring to the *arc length*? (The difference between both would tend to zero when the step size is decreased, but for large steps, it would be important)

Comment: @FrederickCheung good point! But I'm looking for smaller steps sizes :-)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I mean Euclidean distance between two points. So the distance has to account for distances along both x and y axis.

Comment: @Brainstorm yes, it's correct that larger values of the derivative function imply smaller step sizes. It's not clear to me how to apply the derivative function.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I've understood your question correctly you are searching for a solution to this equation for two consequtive points `(θ, f(θ)), (θ+deltaθ , f(θ+deltaθ))` :

```
(θ-(θ+deltaθ))² + (f(θ)-f(θ+deltaθ))² = d²

where f(x) = sin(x)
and   h is the distance in θ between the two points
```

Lets look at `f(x) = x` first:

```
(θ-(θ+deltaθ))² + (θ-(θ+deltaθ))² = d²  <=>

deltaθ² + deltaθ² = d² <=>

deltaθ = +- d/sqrt(2)
```

so a solution can be found for some functions.

Moving on to `f(x) = sin(x)` solving the equation becomes more difficult. I've not been able to find an exact solution. (I've also asked wolfram|alpha and got no result. I assume that w|a knows more about math than me).

There may be a more practical solution though. That could find an approximate solution for small value of deltaθ.

Comment: I think that's the right idea. I usually use `dTheta` or `deltaTheta` instead of `h` to avoid confusion w/ "height". Anyways, I think the function that gives `deltaTheta` is sinusoidal (or at least looks like a sine wave). `deltaTheta` is small initially, then grows until around `pi`, then shrinks again as theta approaches `2 * pi`.

Comment: @SundayMonday Thanks, I think I will update my answer. Where I come from h is usually used to symbolise a small difference, for example when deriving the derivate of a function. So I just went with it.